# Eigenvalues not invariant after similarity transformation

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, precision-and-accuracy, eigenvalues

I have two examples of matrices that undergo a similarity transformation: a random matrix, and an [exclusion-process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymmetric_simple_exclusion_process) inspired matrix. The similarity transformation $\sigma$ is given by an $L \times L$ unit [anti-diagonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-diagonal_matrix)

```
L = 50; (*linear size of matrices; precise value irrelevant*)
e = 0.9; (*parameter to define matrices; precise value irrelevant*)
sigma = Table[If[j == L - i + 1, 1., 0.], {i, L}, {j, L}];
```

That $\sigma$ generates a unitary transformation is checked by $\sigma^2 = 1$, and $|\textrm{det}(\sigma)| = 1$. The random-matrix is created by

```
CreateRandomMatrix[h_, L_] := Module[{m},
m = Table[RandomReal[{-h, h}], {i, L}, {j, L}];
Return[m];
]
```

whereas the second matrix is created by

```
CreateMatrix[h_, L_] := Module[{m},
m = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> -1, Band[{1, 2}] -> 1. - h, Band[{2, 1}] -> h}, {L, L}];
m[[1, 1]] = -h;
m[[L, L]] = -1 + h;
Return[m];
]
```

Now I want to test that the similarity transformation induced by $\sigma$ preserves eigenvalues, as [expected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity) for a similarity transformation. For this I first sort the real and imaginary components of the eigenvalues (before and after the transformation), and then find the absolute maximum differences:

```
MyMat = CreateRandomMatrix[e, L];
evals1 = Eigenvalues[sigma.MyMat.sigma];(*after transformation*)
evals2 = Eigenvalues[MyMat];(*before transformation*)

Max[Abs[Sort[Im[evals1]] - Sort[Im[evals2]]]] (*imaginary part*)
Max[Abs[Sort[Re[evals1]] - Sort[Re[evals2]]]](*real part*)
```

For the case of random-matrix as printed above, I get both above numbers to be $\mathcal{O}(10^{-14})$; however if I replace `CreateRandomMatrix` by `CreateMatrix`, the differences come out:

```
0.2332934635177496` 
0.0506351426786793`
```

These differences get worse as $L$ increases, and, therefore, better as $L$ decreases; I just chose a value of $L$ where the differences are first appreciably apparent.

Any idea why the similarity transformation preserves the eigenvalues for a random matrix but not for the particular one that I have?

Comment: The matrix you construct with CreateMatrix has Det = 0, so the eigenspaces are not guaranteed to be orthogonal. In contrast, the random matrix has nonzero Det.

Comment: I get differences on the order of `10^-14`.  For `L = 500`, I get differences on the order of `10^-13`. (V11.2, MacOS)

Comment: I also cannot reproduce the problem (version 11.3 for macOS).

Comment: @bills I suspected something of the sort (based on getting different numbers for those differences from different Mathematica versions, but never a zero as the others got), but could not fully pin down why . Any further explanations as to why the similarity transformation fails when eigenspaces are nonorthogonal? Possibly related: How do updated versions get it right?

Comment: [`RandomReal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomReal.html) can take an additional argument: `CreateRandomMatrix[h_, L_] := RandomReal[{-h, h}, {L, L}];`